# performant and best way to find min and max from an array

Tags: javascript

I have a array there are some prices. I want to get the min and max. I have a way but I dont know if this way is bad an inefficent. Is there a better/performant way ?

Array:

```
sizes_and_colors: [
      {
        color: 'black',
        size: 'XS',
        amount: 3,
        price: 24.99
      },
      {
        color: 'black',
        size: 'S',
        amount: 4,
        price: 24.99
      },
      {
        color: 'blue',
        size: 'S',
        amount: 5,
        price: 24.95
      },
      {
        color: 'blue',
        size: 'XL',
        amount: 0,
        price: 24.95
      },
      {
        color: 'purple',
        size: null,
        amount: 4,
        price: 22.95
      },
      {
        color: 'beige',
        size: null,
        amount: 4,
        price: 20.99
      },
      {
        color: 'pink',
        size: 'S',
        amount: 2,
        price: 20.99
      },
      {
        color: 'green',
        size: null,
        amount: 4,
        price: 20.99
      },
      {
        color: 'silver',
        size: null,
        amount: 4,
        price: 20.99
      },
      {
        color: 'yellow',
        size: null,
        amount: 4,
        price: 20.99
      },
```

get lowest/highest pirce:

```
// get lowest price of the arr of sizes and colors
export const getLowestPrice = (sizes_and_colors: any) => {
  let arr: number[] = [];
   sizes_and_colors.map((el:any) => {
      if(el.price) {
        arr.push(el.price);
      }
   })
   return Math.min(...arr);
}

// get highest price of the arr of sizes and colors
export const getHighestPrice = (sizes_and_colors: any) => {
  let arr: number[] = [];
   sizes_and_colors.map((el:any) => {
      if(el.price) {
        arr.push(el.price);
      }
   })
   return Math.max(...arr);
}
```

I am very thankful for your answers and help!!!!
...........................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Theory:

Finding any specific element in an unsorted array is an `O(n)` operation, so a single loop over all array elements. You currently seem to be doing one loop to extract the numeric components of an object, and then feeding them to `Math.min()` or `Math.max()`, which will have to do another loop. So you're doing `O(2n)` for one value, `O(4n)` for both.

If you know you're gonna need both, you can just keep two variables and check for both min and max in every loop iteration.

```
let min = Infinity, max = -Infinity;
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
{
    let p = arr[i].price;
    if(p < min) min = p;
    if(p > max) max = p;
}
```

Certainly not idiomatic JavaScript, but this way you get both values in `O(n)`.

### Practice:

Run tests. JavaScript engines apply all sorts of crazy optimisations, and it may very well be possible that builtins like `Array.map()` and `Math.min()`/`Math.max()` enjoy better optimisation than a hand-rolles JavaScript loop.

Also, beware of diminishing returns. If you expect the array to not contain at least a thousand elements, then worrying about performance on searching it is almost certainly a waste of time, and going with Samathingamajig's answer is likely preferrable for readability.

But if performance truly is critical in your case, benchmark a raw loop against the other solutions. Do a couple million iterations, run them across different browsers, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Just `map` to the price and take the max/min

```js
// get lowest price of the arr of sizes and colors
export const getLowestPrice = (sizes_and_colors: any) => {
   return Math.min(...sizes_and_colors.map((el) => el.price));
}

// get highest price of the arr of sizes and colors
export const getHighestPrice = (sizes_and_colors: any) => {
   return Math.max(...sizes_and_colors.map((el) => el.price));
}
```